# TCP socket stops receiving data until closed

Tags: ruby, actionscript-3, flash, networking, tcp

I have a really weird problem that is driving me crazy.

I have a Ruby server and a Flash client (Action Script 3). It's a multiplayer game.

The problem is that everything is working perfect and then, suddenly, a random player stops receiving data. When the server closes the connection because of inactivity, about 20-60 seconds later, the client receives all the buffered data.

The client uses `XMLsocket` for retrieving data, so the way the client receives data is not the problem.

```
socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler);
function connectHandler(event)
{
    sendData(sess);
}

function sendData(dat)
{
    trace("SEND: " + dat);
    addDebugData("SEND: " + dat)
    if (socket.connected) {
        socket.send(dat);
    } else {
        addDebugData("SOCKET NOT CONNECTED")
    }
}

socket.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, dataHandler);
function dataHandler(e:DataEvent) {
    var data:String = e.data;
    workData(data);
}
```

The server flushes data after every write, so is not a flushing problem:

```
sock.write(data + DATAEOF)
sock.flush()
```

`DATAEOF` is null char, so the client parses the string.

When the server accepts a new socket, it sets `sync` to true, to autoflush, and `TCP_NODELAY` to true too:

```
newsock = serverSocket.accept
newsock.sync = true
newsock.setsockopt(Socket::IPPROTO_TCP, Socket::TCP_NODELAY, true)
```

This is my research:

Info: I was dumping netstat data to a file each second.

- When the client stops receiving data, netstat shows that socket status is still `ESTABLISHED`.
- Some seconds after that, send-queue grows accordingly to data sent.
- tcpflow shows that packets are sent 2 times.
- When the server closes the socket, socket status changes to `FIN_WAIT1`, as expected. Then, tcpflow shows that all buffered data is sent to the client, but the client don't receives data. some seconds after that, connection dissapears from netstat and tcpflow shows that the same data is sent again, but this time the client receives the data so starts sending data to the server and the server receives it. But it's too late... server has closed connection.

I don't think it's an OS/network problem, because I've changed from a VPS located in Spain to Amazon EC2 located in Ireland and the problem still remains.

I don't think it's a client network problem too, because this occurs dozens of times per day, and the average quantity of online users is about 45-55, with about 400 unique users a day, so the ratio is extremely high.

**EDIT:**
I've done more research. I've changed the server to C++.

When a client stops sending data, after a while the server receives a "Connection reset by peer" error. In that moment, tcpdump shows me that the client sent a RST packet, this could be because the client closed the connection and the server tried to read, but... why the client closed the connection? I think the answer is that the client is not the one closing the connection, is the kernel. Here is some info: http://scie.nti.st/2008/3/14/amazon-s3-and-connection-reset-by-peer

`Basically, as I understand it, Linux kernels 2.6.17+ increased the maximum size of the TCP window/buffer, and this started to cause other gear to wig out, if it couldn’t handle sufficiently large TCP windows. The gear would reset the connection, and we see this as a “Connection reset by peer” message.`

I've followed the steps and now it seems that the server is closing connections only when the client losses its connection to internet.

I'm going to add this as an answer so people know a bit mroe about this.

Comment: The grow of the send queue does not necessarily mean that the problem is on the server side. Server needs to keep data in the queue until client acknowledges it, so the problem may be caused by the client not reading data.

Comment: Ok, nice advice, going to edit post.

Comment: I don't know Flash architecture but similar problems are often caused by a deadlock in client that prevents it from reading input data. Are you sure that all event listeners that are invoked by a thread that invokes your dataHandler() function are non-blocking? If you block this thread it may prevent the client from reading data. Maybe you block the thread by waiting for a user input?

Comment: Flash is not multithreaded, when an event is 'working' no more events can be called until that event ends, and the code is not locked because in the client log I see that the player is sending chat messages like "this is not working!" to the server (Of course the message don't reaches the server), so the code is running, not locked. Thanks for your advice by the way.

Comment: First off let me say no matter how irrelevant you may think it is "Post The Code". Now with that being said your issue looks to me like it is a policy issue. But I can't tell how you are handling it since there is no code.

Comment: My code is about 6k client/server lines, I don't know what code to post because I don't know where the problem is :-/, that's because I've posted the code that the client and the server use to connect between them. If you mean a Flash security policy file, everything is ok, when the client request to the server the policy file, it's sent and then the client can connect to the server and start playing. The problem is that , when the user has played some time (sometimes is 30 minutes, other times hours) then occurs the behavior I've explained in the post. Btw, thanx for giving me ideas.

Comment: By the way, I'm going to add a bit more code in a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is that the kernel is the one closing the connection. Here is some info: http://scie.nti.st/2008/3/14/amazon-s3-and-connection-reset-by-peer

`Basically, as I understand it, Linux kernels 2.6.17+ increased the maximum size of the TCP window/buffer, and this started to cause other gear to wig out, if it couldn’t handle sufficiently large TCP windows. The gear would reset the connection, and we see this as a “Connection reset by peer” message.`

I've followed the steps and now it seems that the server is closing connections only when the client losses its connection to internet.